# Are references / pointers guaranteed to be valid after moving std::deque?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, deque

Is it safe to assume that any pointers I have to elements inside of an `std::deque` are still valid after moving the deque to another one with the move constructor?

For `std::vector` I cannot see any reason why they wouldn't be, but I'm not familiar enough with `std::deque` to be sure I can make the same assumption.

Comment: Don't assume; read the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers to elements would remain valid. After [move construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/deque#Notes):

> After container move construction (overload (8)), references, pointers, and iterators (other than the end iterator) to other remain valid, but refer to elements that are now in `*this`. The current standard makes this guarantee via the blanket statement in [[container.requirements.general]/12](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#12), and a more direct guarantee is under consideration via [LWG 2321](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2321).

Comment: Be careful, in that move assignment and move construction are not the same thing.  Last I looked into it, move-assigned vectors do not make this guarantee (!), I do not know about deques.